# JQGRID - Prevent adding empty row after execution of afterSubmit

Tags: jqgrid

I have a grid where I put a custom button in the navgrid for inserting totally different data in another table so I used editGridRow("new",…) where in the php url I just post data to a different table. Actually I am stuck with the issue if I submit the form, even if I settled reloadAfterSubmit:false, it add a new empty row in the grid…

You can see the piece of code here:

```
jQuery("#"+child_table_id).navButtonAdd("#"+pager_id,
{
caption:"Insert",buttonicon:"ui-icon-arrow-1-se",
onClickButton:function(){ 
    var rows = jQuery("#"+child_table_id).getRowData(); 
    if ( rows.length != 0 ) { 
        jQuery("#"+child_table_id).editGridRow("new",{height:140,width:420,url:"http://.../edit_datatable.php?table_name=mytable&fact=insert&q=1&flag=yes&ref_id="+id_row,
    reloadAfterSubmit:false, 
    recreateForm:true, 
    closeOnEscape:true, 
    closeAfterAdd:true,
    addCaption:'Insert',
savekey: [true,13],
    bSubmit:'Save',
    afterSubmit:function(response, postdata){ alert('inserting to a total different table...'); return {0:true} } 
});
}
},
position:"last",
title:"Insert new step...",
cursor:"pointer"
});
```

I tried even to add:

```
onClickButton:function(){ $("#"+child_table_id).setGridParam({ datatype: 'local' }); }

afterSubmit:function(response, postdata){ return {0:true} },

onclickSubmit : function(params, posdata) {return {0:true} },

afterComplete:function(response, postdata, formid) { $("#"+child_table_id).setGridParam({ datatype: 'json' }); }
```

but it added anyway a row in the grid…

So how I can prevent  jqGrid to add a new empty grid and refreshing the grid?…

Answer (score 1):

You wrote about "inserting totally different data in another table", but you add button to the navigator bar of the grid `"#"+child_table_id` and your code inside of `onClickButton` callback adds new row to **the same grid**:

```js
jQuery("#"+child_table_id).navButtonAdd("#"+pager_id, { ...
    onClickButton:function(){
        ...
        jQuery("#"+child_table_id).editGridRow("new", ...
    }
 });
```

If you really want to add new row to *another* grid you should use id of another in the `editGridRow` (like `jQuery("#"+another_table_id).editGridRow("new",...`).

Comment: Hello Oleg, first thank you for answering. I'll explain better...I am playing with rows independently between them. In the specific I am saying total different table, not grid, but really I am adding in the same table but without adding in the same grid but creating a new grid node like it's independent but related to selected row in the current grid where I click on the custom button. At least is there a possible alternative to avoid callback inserting in the same grid? Thanks! Luigi

Comment: @LuigiN.Puleio: You can avoid inserting in the same grid and insert the data in another grid. To do this you should apply the `editGridRow` to the *destination* grid like `jQuery("#"+another_table_id).editGridRow("new",...)`. Probably you don't want to insert the data in any grid? Probably you want just sent the data to the server which insert it in the *database table*? In the case you should use [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or some simplified version of the fumction like [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Comment: @LuigiN.Puleio: Sorry, but I understand nothing more. You wrote "inserting totally different data in another table", then you wrote "to add a record in the same table loading the editor and insert data but without inserting in any grid". Do you want add row to the grid or you want recreate grid with another data? If you need any help you should describe more clear what you want to do and which problem you currently has.

Comment: No Oleg, I wanted just to add a record in the same table loading the editor and insert data but without inserting in any grid. Then right after inserted the row, I would just insert a new jqGrid() right after the current grid loading that record right inserted. To be more precise, I have a main grid with some records that are subgrids; inside I put a new grid with a record and two columns YES and NO which are buttons. Press those buttons would append a new grid after the current one. In the navgrid I added a custom button where it would insert, not append, a new grid. Is there a way?...

Comment: @LuigiN.Puleio: Sorry, I can't follow you, but I suspect that you try to use jqGrid and row editing in a wrong way.

Comment: Hello Oleg. Here there's a screenshot about how I am using jqGrid: http://www.ensvarese.it/screenshot.png ... as you can see, there's in navgrid an Insert button where I would insert a new jqgrid right after the current grid where I press the button. It's like I have a tree of steps connected from "YES" and "NO" reference ID fields... so I thought to call editGridRow to have form as like as the colModel but not displaying in the grid. Is there a direction for that?... Thanks Luigi

Comment: @LuigiN.Puleio: What you mean under "to have form as like as the colModel but not displaying in the grid"? What you want not display in the grid? `editGridRow` is not just for displaying a form. Even if you call it with "new" as `rowid` it will first send the new data to the server per ajax and then add the row to the grid or reload the grid from the server. It seems to me that you try use `editGridRow` in the place where you need just use [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).